# Saving xml file in Stand alone machine using actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript

While developing an application (for KIOSK) using Actionscript I am facing the trouble to store xml data in that machine. What is the way to save xml file  using actionscript?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that depends on whether you are using AIR or Flash projector, or the Flash plugin. If you're using AIR, and need to be a little bit more verbose, then I would recommend that you store the XML with the [SQLite bindings.](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/sqlite_db_api_in_air.html). In all other cases, I would recommend using a [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using actionscript only to build swf file (using FlahDevelop) and later on the swf file is converted to flash projector. SharedObject could be a good option but the xml file I am using will grow as many users will interact with the KIOSK. I have no idea about SQLite but I will try on it. Looking for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Flash does not have the ability to save files without user interaction. In a kiosk, I assume you want to save data without having the user have access to the file system. So you will need to use another technology to do this> 
The most obvious is Adobe AIR, which gives flash all of the powers and permsiions of a desktop application. 
There are also commercial solutions for creating enhanced projectors (Such as Zinc, and ScreenTime) but I cannot think of a use case for them other than as screensavers, since AIR has been introduced.
In air you will be able to save files, or use an SQLite databse.

The code for saving a file  using AIR looks something like this:

```
import flash.filesystem.*;  
import flash.events.Event;  

function saveFile():void {  
    var file:File=File.desktopDirectory;  
    file=file.resolvePath("test.txt");  
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);  
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes("Hi this file was saved from AIR application without dialog");  
    fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);  
    fileStream.close();  


function fileClosed(event:Event):void {  
    trace("closed event fired");  
}  
}  
saveFile();
```

Posted From here:
http://askmeflash.com/tutorial/6/save-file-in-adobe-air-without-dialog-window

Comment: Thank you so much. Upvoted your answer since I already marked cwallenpoole's  as answer.